# Is there some way to better organize api calls with useFetch in nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

With previous iterations of nuxt, it was possible to use @nuxtjs/axios and achieve something similar to what is mentioned on this page https://blog.lichter.io/posts/nuxt-api-call-organization-and-decoupling/, I was wondering if there's a way to do this with nuxt 3 and useFetch